# Printing UI Without Vowels Using Loops Without replaceAll(); in Java

Tags: java, string, loops

I am trying to take user input and modify it so that I print the string without any vowels. I have been able to do this successfully with the following code.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
    String word = in.next();

    String newString = word.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]","1");
    System.out.printf("%s", newString);
```

However, I am trying to get the same effect by using a loop without the above method, replaceAll(). I have tried one other time, but got mixed up in the logic and restarted. My latest attempt is below and I cannot understand why it will not run properly. I will enter a string and without any error message it will not print back anything. The only time I get it to work is when I give it single characters to find in the string using something like

```
if(letter.contains("a"))
```

If the condition is found true it will print back a string of a's, however, this does not work for any combination of characters, only single ones. My complete code is below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
   String word = in.next();
   int i = 0;

   while (i < word.length()){
       String letter = word.substring(i, (i+1));
       if(letter.contains("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]")){
           System.out.printf("%s",letter);
       }
       i++;
   }
  }
}
```

I am simply trying to find a way to complete this program only using conditionals, loops, UI, and only the methods length(), contains() or indexOf(), charAt(), and substring(x,y). Thanks in advance for any help I hope I have provided enough information.

Here is some sample output:

```
Enter a word: 
Jordan
```

After I entered the word the program stops.

Comment: The string `"b"` (for example) cannot contain the string `"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"`.  It's much too short.

Comment: Sorry, I edited and added the [] around the letters I was looking for. Unfortunately still the same error, not getting any output. I put a sample output in the question to hopefully clarify a bit more, thanks.

Comment: `contains` does not use regexes, and using `[]` is creating a regex.  Nevertheless, you *can* solve the problem using `contains()`, and I thought you were on the right track but just made a little mistake.  You can make a simple change to the code you originally had (without `[]`).  Think about it a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to convert your string to an array of characters [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) and then compared with a case and add a new chain StringBuilder

```
 String word = in.next();
     StringBuilder bul = new StringBuilder();
     for (char arg : word.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
         switch(arg)
         {
             case 'a': System.out.println("A");break;
             case 'e': System.out.println("E");break;
             case 'i': System.out.println("I");break;
             case 'o': System.out.println("O");break;
             case 'u': System.out.println("U");break;
             default:
                 bul.append(arg);
         }
     }
     System.out.println(bul); //String not Vowels
```

in your code might change why a selected character with subtring can never contain such a long string like that `"[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]"`

```
if(letter.contains("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]")){...}
```

for

```
if("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]".contains(letter.toLowerCase())){...}
```

Comment: Changing the if statement worked and thank you for the additional method. Can you explain a bit more why the latter way of creating the contains() method works and not the one I created? I am just trying to learn the ins and outs of everything so that I can understand as much as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Because I did was that obtenia a character of the string using `substring()`and then wondered if that character contained a whole string of characters `"[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]"` logically `n` can not contain `n+n` characters that always `returns false`, otherwise it would instead ask if `n` contains `n-1` which is the most logical and more likely to return `true`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scanner.useDelimeter(Pattern pattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)) with `regex`.  The `regex`for removing vowel is - **[^aeiou]+**

If you want to ignore case then use this pattern - **(?i)[^aeiou]+** .

And finally try the following code snippet -

```
scanner.useDelimeter(Pattern.compile("[^aeiou]+"));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say,

```
if(letter.contains("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"))
```

your code will check if `letter` has the exact sequence of letters `bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz`

In other words, it won't not check if any of these letters individually exists in the `String`.

Instead, you could go like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        String currentLetter = String.valueOf(word.charAt(i));
        if (!currentLetter.matches("a|e|i|o|u"))
            System.out.print(currentLetter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

other way of doing is

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter input String");
String input = s.next();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

for(char c : input.toLowerCase().toCharArray())
  if( c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' ){}
  else  sb.append(c+"");'

System.out.println("Given input without vowels : "+sb);
```